# how to keep view on top of key board in android

Tags: android

This is my xml :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_12"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_12"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cl_28">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.TextDarkGrey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                android:text="Enter your password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_fingerprint_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cl_16"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                android:text="Enter your Tesco password to activate fingerprint ID"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_input_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cl_20"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_fingerprint_description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_close"
                style="@style/Typeface.Body.TescoBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cl_24"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_8"
                android:text="Cancel"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_submit"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_input_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_submit"
                style="@style/Typeface.Body.TescoBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cl_24"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_8"
                android:text="Submit"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_input_text"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my code written in class

```
et_input_text.setOnFocusChangeListener(object  : View.OnFocusChangeListener{
            override fun onFocusChange(v: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
                if(hasFocus)
                scroll_view.scrollTo(0,scroll_view.bottom)
            }

        })

in manifest file, I have added 



<activity
            android:name=".features.common.customview.FingerPrintWithPasswordDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@style/PaddedScreenDialogTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I am trying to set my submit and cancel button on top of the keyboard but it is hidden inside the keyboard please suggest to me how to achieve this.
[image]

please see in this screen Submit and the canal is hidden i want to scroll full bottom so that it should show cancel and submit button.

Comment: I tried your layout and  by removing android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", it worked

Comment: Ok thanks let me check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try by removing

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```